# Getopt() Error Checking

Tags: c, error-handling, getopt

I am trying to make it so that getopt can handle certain flags, but I am having trouble implementing the error handling using getopt. I want to prevent duplicate flags such as '-s 1 -s 1', and having too many arguments for a flag '-s 1 2' both of these should exit the program.

```
 int opt; //command flags
 while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:f:")) != -1){
 switch(opt){
  case 's':
    printf("%s\n", optarg);
    printf("%i\n", optind);
    break;
  case 'f':
    printf("%s\n", optarg);
    printf("%i\n", optind);
    break;
  default:
    //unknown command flags
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage:  fred [ -s symbol-table-file ] [ -f fred-program-file ]\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

Too many arguments (e.g., program -s f1 -f f2 hello). Duplicate flags (e.g., program -s f1 -s f2). Both should exit the program

Comment: The extra argument has to be detected after the loop; it will appear as an 'unconsumed' argument and `optind < argc` will hold when the loop exits.  The repeated argument will need something like `int sflag = 0;` before the loop and `if (sflag++ > 0) { …chastise user and exit… }` in the `case 's':` code.

Answer (score 1):

For each option, you may maintain a flag to see if the option has already been encountered or not. Duplicate options are detected with the help of these flags.

```
int c, sflag=0, fflag=0;
while( (c=getopt(argc, argv, "s:f:"))!=-1 )
{
    switch(c)
    {
    case 's':
        if(sflag!=0)
        {
            //fprintf(stderr, "\n dup s option");
            return 1; //duplicate s option
        }   
        sflag++;
        //printf("\ns flag: %s", optarg);
        break;
    case 'f':
        if(fflag!=0)
        {
            //fprintf(stderr, "\n dup f option");
            return 1; //duplicate f option
        }   
        fflag++;
        //printf("\nf flag: %s", optarg);
        break;
    case '?':
        if(isprint(optopt))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option %c", optopt);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nUnknown option character x%x", optopt);
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

`optind` will have the index of the next `argv[]` which is still to be examined. After all the options have been taken care of, in your program there should be exactly one non-option argument.

So, `optind` must be equal to `argc-1` for a correct usage of the command.

```
if(optind != argc-1) //exactly one non-option argument is expected
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nInvalid number of arguments.");
    return 1;
}
```